# How to terminate(or abort) a timetask immediately

Tags: java, task

I want to terminate(or abort) a task immediately when it is running, not to wait its ending. I search in JDK, the Timer class and the TimerTask class not satisfied, their cancel method is not proper for me, for the task will contiue to execute util it finish, but I want to stop it immediately.

What should I do? I serach for Spring and Quartz, but no good idea...

Comment: You cannot cancel a task that has started. You could look at the `ExecutorService` API - specifically the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). The [`ScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) provides a [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) method that allows a running task to be interrupted; however your task must be interruptible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is recommended to do in a multi threaded environment as it can break your code in all sorts of ways. For example imagine you are half way through changing something and suddenly your thread gets killed leaving it in a half-modified state. Because it is not recommended no easy way is provided to do it.

The correct way to do this is to use a Thread and `interrupt` it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Inside your Thread code you can check `isInterrupted()` at times where it would be appropriate to abort and abort, but the abort is controlled by the running thread which is the only thing that knows when it is safe to do so.

The `ScheduledExecutorService` also allows you to work with a `ScheduledFuture` and `cancel` that, which then works in the same way as interrupting the thread does.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)